# How to read user input and convert it to a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, serverside-javascript

I am right now using the API of [yodaspeak](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yoda-speak)
And I made some small changes on the codes.
I want the user to input what words to change
here is my node.js code

```
var YodaSpeak = require('yoda-speak');
var yoda = new YodaSpeak('hZy4MAVwtbmshFTdDuJSiMxKIxWsp1JSor1jsnuNeLjEVTnbXv');

console.log("Please enter the sentence you want to convert:");
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
var chunk = process.stdin.read();
if (chunk !== null) {
  yoda.convert(toString(chunk),
function(err, result) {
if (!err) {
    console.log(result.toString());
} else {
    console.log(err);
}
})
  }
});
```

the console always tells error message
I need to how to get the user input and convert it to string and assign it to a variable.

BTW in advance we need to install yoda-speak

```
%npm install --save yoda-speak
```

the error message is

```
Please enter the sentence you want to convert
fjesil
[object undefined].
```

Comment: *"the console always tells error message"* What error message? What line did it happen on? what file?

Comment: oh Sorry I will upload it right away. The Problem that I am having is that I don't know how to make a prompt and replace the string in yoda.convert with user input

Comment: i don't understand your code... `words` is defined as undefined, and then you use `words` as the name of an event you're listening to, so that event handler shouldn't ever run.

Comment: Additionally, you're calling yoda.convert way too early. see the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin

Comment: I mean, I want to name the sentence user inputted "words" and then use it for converting. It is like the same sctructure as the reference page one.

Comment: in the reference page, there is a string in the place of words

Comment: I'm talking about this line: `process.stdin.on(words` I'm completely ignoring the yodaspeak portion of your question at the moment, because the part before it isn't working yet.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry that I still cannot understand it will, I read the reference but still don't know how to output the input as a variable or a string. Sorry

Comment: For example, if you run this code, you get undefined before even entering any text. http://pastebin.com/jpkCxzdz as expected, because you need an on data listener and an on end listener.

Comment: I modified my code and attached it as the second version

Answer (score 0):

yodaspeak isn't where your problem lies, it's with how you're accepting text from the console. `process.stdin.on(` is adding an event listener, and the event you're interested in is named `data`, not `undefined`. Below is how you would console.log() each word that is input in the console:

```
console.log("Please enter the sentence you want to convert");
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('data', function (words) {
    console.log(words);
});
```

Now all you have to do is tie yodaspeak back into it.

```
console.log("Please enter the sentence you want to convert");
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('data', function (words) {
    yoda.convert(words, function (err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(result.toString());
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot, it seems that I need make up on my basis of programming, My problem is solved. Thank you very much

Comment: You can omit the `.resume()` call if you're using a more recent version of node.